# Is there a way to deal with a string of bits in C++

Tags: c++, performance, buffer

I am trying to write a **very** efficient C++ class that defines a new floating point type with much more precision than the primitive data types. See my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258810/should-i-expect-gmps-mpf-class-to-be-much-slower-than-the-primitive-data-type-d) for more background.

To start I am using static allocation in my `hp_float.hpp`:

```
class hp_float {
private:
  unsigned char buf[48];
public:
  hp_float();
  hp_float operator+(const hp_float& h);
};
```

My problem is that, eventually, in order to implement that `operator+` I am going to have to use bit-wise operations including `<<` and `>>`. I saw that this can be tricky with these buffers, as seen in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367616/bitwise-shifting-array-of-chars).

I would like to do shifting without the need for a loop. I could manually unroll it in my implementation, but ultimately I want to treat the buffer as a contiguous string of bits like any other primitive data type:

```
hp_float hp_float::operator+(const hp_float& h) {
  [type???] this_sign = buf >> (48*8-1);

  ...
}
```

**My Question:** Is this not possible? Do have any advice one doing what I want with the best performance?

Comment: Note that in many cases, the compiler/optimizer will automatically unroll any loop you come up with, if it thinks it's worthwhile to do so -- therefore avoiding loops in your source code may not be so important anyway.

Comment: `std::bitset` maybe?

Comment: Oh, I didn’t know about  `std::bitset`. And it looks like from the notes at the bottom of the cppreference that it is static allocation if the size is known at compile time. Is that correct?

Comment: @redmoncoreyl `std::betset`'s size _must_ be known at compile time since it's a template parameter.  Also, the `noexcept` guarantee of its constructor effectively means its storage can't be dynamically allocated.

Comment: If you are looking for speed concerning bit shift I would consider to change your array type. `unsigned char` looks like you intend to process the data byte wise. That means every byte is converted to `unsigned` before any arithmetic operation (including bit shift) and converted back when stored (although the "conversions" are probably trivial). If you make your array instead of `unsigned int` you will process much more bits per iteration step (and there is no conversion in arithmetic operations, even no trivial). If you have to consider carries then `unsigned short` could be a compromise.

Comment: "string" of bits? Series of bits?

Comment: I was thinking of a [mathematical string](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/String.html).